# iOS auto layout's modification in custom view doesn't work until viewDidAppear gets called

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I've got view controller (using Storyboards if matters). Controller got custom view inside it let's call it `AView`. The view is laid out on storyboard as UIView object with custom class set. AView's contents are on separate XIB because I need this highly reusable. Here's how code looks like:

```
class VC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var aView: AView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        aView.setup(false) //doesn't work
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        aView.setup(false) //doesn't work
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        aView.setup(false) //do work but glitches
    }

}

class AView: UIView {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        //init stuff: loading nib, adding view from it
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var someView: UIView! //this view has all constraints which are required and additional rightConstraint which is inactive, for future use
    @IBOutlet var leftConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var rightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    func setup(shouldBeOnLeft: Bool) {
        leftConstraint.active = true
        rightConstraint.active = false
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

I need to setup this view before it appears, based on some parameters. I'm modifying only its internal content from inside. If I call `aView.setup(shouldBeOnLeft:)` in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` constraints don't update or maybe do but I don't see changes. If I move it to `viewDidAppear` it works but obviously I see misplaced views for a while (state before setup).

The question is: how to get it work as intended and without view's manipulation form view controller and independent on how and where `setup` method is called unless it's inside or right after VC's `viewDidLoad`? Only thing that VC needs to know is to call setup with parameter.

Comment: params doesn't matter. What matters is that based on it I would like modify constraints. i.e. `if params.count == 4 { constraintA.active = false }`

Comment: @beyowulf I don't get it - where am I looking at VC's frame?

Comment: @beyowulf I've edited example to be more straightforward on what setup actually do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured that out - but I don't actually like it in 100%

```
class VC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var aView: AView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        aView.setup(false) //now it does work
    }
 }

class AView: UIView {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        //init stuff: loading nib, adding view from it
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var someView: UIView! //this view has all constraints which are required and additional rightConstraint which is inactive, for future use
    @IBOutlet var leftConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var rightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    func setup(shouldBeOnLeft: Bool) {
        self.yesIfLeft = shouldBeOnLeft
    }

    private var yesIfLeft = false {
        didSet{
            self.updateLayout()
        }
    }

    private func updateLayout() {
        leftConstraint.active = self.yesIfLeft
        rightConstraint.active = !self.yesIfLeft
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.updateLayout()
    }
}
```

Whole point is to keep reference to settings that cause layout change and update them also in `layoutSubviews()`. Doing this way VC doesn't have to know about internals of `AView` (that's a big plus for me) but requires that `AView` holds it's configuration which is some extra work to do. I'm not marking this answer as accepted for now because maybe someone will have some better idea.

Answer (score 4):

You should call it inside  `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, at this point it have set the view parameters, and you can manipulate the view before is presented to the user (so, no glitches)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLayoutSubviews

> **Discussion**
>    Called to notify the view controller that its view has just laid out its subviews.

Comment: So basically there's no way for custom view to manage its own internal constraints after self's `init` and its controller's `viewDidLayoutSubviews`? Or rather it is possible but you won't see this change. Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: I am confuse with your question, after viewDidLayoutSubviews, the constraints are take in to "place" in the view, and you can adjust the position of the elements, before it, the elements are not placed, got it?

Comment: check my edited question. I've edited it to show exactly what I did, what worked and what not.

Comment: if I move `setup` method to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` it works but then VC must be aware that some properties or methods triggers subview internal constraints' change which I don't like.